# List of services that support iOS Social Framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, social-framework

I've been trying to find a list of social networks that support iOS Social Framework but had no luck.

I couldn't even find whether this is something only supported by those companies doing deals with Apple or if any social network can plug into the framework to support their authentication.

Most posts and articles about the framework only talk about how to integrate it with Twitter and Facebook but don't really talk about others.

Can someone enlighten me how this works?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this isn't the preferred way to integrate any more (if you want to work with arbitrary services).

Instead bring up the Share Sheet which will let the user share your content with any app they have installed that has a proper share extension for that content.

Comment: I am not trying to use this to share content. Trying to use this as an Oauth alternative so I can make subsequent API calls to each service. I think it's much more convenient for at least Twitter and Facebook. What would be an alternative if I wanted to work with arbitrary services in this case?

Comment: There are some projects out there to do that. This one is popular: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit